# Extension method, when called on a null object, is called on the wrong type

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods

```
fun main() {
    val set: Set<Int>?
    set = null
    val emptySet: Set<Int> = set.orEmpty()
}
```

Can't figure out why even when explicitly typing the set variable as Set <Int>? the compiler considers that in the extension method *set.orEmpty ()* set - is a string and, accordingly, crashes with an error:

> Kotlin: Type mismatch: inferred type is String but Set was expected

But when declaring and initializing in one line, everything happens correctly:

```
fun main() {
    val set: Set<Int>? = null
    val emptySet: Set<Int> = set.orEmpty()
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce it and as far as I can tell, it is a compiler bug, and a very serious one!

Comment: `set = null` smart casts the `set` to `Nothing?` (which is valid) and then it seems `String?.orEmpty()` is selected over `Set<T>?.orEmpty()` because it's not generic (thus considered more specific). This is unfortunate, because the overload resolution doesn't take into account the non-smart-cast original type of `set`

Comment: That said, this can only really happen if we now at compile time that this `set` is null, so there is no real point in calling `orEmpty` in the first place - it could just be `emptySet()` directly.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're observing can be explained by the interaction of two Kotlin features:

- first, the type of `set` variable is narrowed to `Nothing?` as a result of a smart cast after the assignment of `null` value to it. The smart cast after an assignment can be useful in cases when it narrows variable type to a more specific type, but narrowing to `Nothing?` does more harm than good.
- second, among all overloads of `orEmpty` function available for a value of type `Nothing?`, the non-generic one `String?.orEmpty()` is chosen due to the specific rule of Kotlin overload resolution: a non-generic candidate is preferred to generic ones.

This behavior indeed can be puzzling, so I've reported this problem as [KT-50661](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-50661).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to the fact that the compiler is not so smart that it could deduce that the code *set = null* will be executed exactly once – it could be zero times or more than once.

If you know that it will run exactly one, you can tell the compiler by using a feature called *kotlin.contracts:*

```
import kotlin.contracts.ExperimentalContracts
import kotlin.contracts.InvocationKind
import kotlin.contracts.contract

@ExperimentalContracts
fun main() {
  val set: Set<Int>?
  once { set = null }
  val emptySet: Set<Int> = set.orEmpty()
}

@ExperimentalContracts
fun once(lambda: () -> Unit) {
  contract { callsInPlace(lambda, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE) }
  lambda()
}
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.contracts/

Comment: It can't be more than once in the OP's example. `val` should guarantee as much.

Comment: But – as I wrote – the compiler cannot deduce that.

Comment: It doesn’t matter what it can deduce or how many times it is changed. The type of the variable is explicitly a Set, regardless of whether it has been initialized so it should not be calling `String?.orEmpty()`.

Comment: I just got up and toyed around further with it. If you use _null.also { set = it }_ instead of the naked _set = null_ it works. And when you go to StandardKt.class the implementation of _also_ is exactly the same callsInPlace-contract with InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE.

Comment: At some point earlier this year I read somewhere about why the compiler is not able to deduce the type in certain kinds of assignments. If I find that page I will post the link here.

Comment: I don't understand why how often (or whether at all) something is assigned to a variable at runtime should matter for a compile time MRO resolution. Extension methods are only resolved statically after all. This looks like an obvious compiler bug.

Comment: @Voo I believe it has to do with smart casting and flow typing. The fact that the variable is assigned zero, one, or more times can be used to narrow its type down at compile time - thus apparently changing the resolved overload. Ironically, smart-casting to `Nothing?` here leaves us with less information than when it was a `Set<Int>?` as far as this overload resolution is concerned